# Messages sent to mailing list not shown in Gmail

Tags: gmail, mailing-list

When I send an email from my Gmail account to a mailing list I never receive the messages I have sent in the inbox.

Since I use an external account, which I import with POP3 into Gmail, I can see on that account's email web interface that the list does send my messages back to me but somehow when Gmail fetches them it doesn't display them.

I suspect this is because the Message ID in the sent and received messages is identical and assumes it is the same message and doesn't display it.

As anyone seen this before? Is there a way of circumventing it?

I really would like to receive my own messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced with the same problem. Google can't manage to display your email both in inbox and outbox with the same ID. Since your mail was a sent email firstly google does not change it later.

There are two ways (according to my knowledge :) ) to handle this issue:

1. create a filter in your gmail (sent from your emial and sent to the list) and move the filtered emails to the inbox
2. change your external account to forward the email to your gmail instead of using pop3 integration

Comment: I've confirmed my theory at [this url](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6588?hl=en). Gmail "de-duplicates" emails with the same `Message-ID` header. Since `Mailman` doesn't touch this header Gmail will only show one copy of it. Your solutions are also no good because 1. I would like to see both copies of the message (outbound and inbound) and only the one that was sent is visible and 2. forward or pop will keep the MessageID intact... Only if `Mailman` would change the `MessageID` it would work.

Comment: Archived version of Fabricio's link: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915095411/https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6588?hl=en)